# Uncaught TypeError: notParked is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm using React Redux and superagent to create an app that shows a list of cars that are parked in a specific parking, all by using APIs. I got around to showing the list of the cars.

Each car has a boolean property called parked, parked=true means that the car is actually in the parking and should show up on the list.

Each car in the list has a button in front of it and when you click it, you modify the property of the car to parked=false which means that the car is not parked anymore and should be removed from the list.

So what i have to do is use a PUT reqest to modify the value in the database and refresh the list. pretty simple.

I already created the PUT request and function and created a button in the list and made an event so whenever you click that button it excecutes the function for that specific item.

**Problem : **: clicking the button causes an error `Uncaught TypeError: notParked is not a function at Object.VoitureList._this.onSubmit [as onClick]`

here's the code:
this is my function inside actions.js, it takde the id of the element and modifies the property to false:

```
export const ParkedModified = (voiture) => ({
    type: VOITURE_MODIFIED,
    voiture
});
//Mod
export const notParked = (id) =>{
    return(dispatch)=>{
        return requests.put(
            `/voitures/${id}`,
            {
                parked: false
            }
        ).then(response => dispatch(ParkedModified(response)))
    }
}
```

and this is my voiturelist.js where I show my list:

```
import {notParked} from "../actions/actions";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    notParked
};
export class VoitureList extends React.Component {

    onSubmit = event => {
        const {notParked}= this.props;
        const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');
        console.log(id);
        return notParked(id);
     }


    render() {
        const {voitureList}=this.props;

        return (

            <div className="card mb-3 mt-3 shadow-sm">
                { voitureList.map(voiture => {
                    return (

                      <div className="card-body border-bottom" key={voiture.id}>
                        <p className="card-text mb-0">
                          {voiture.matricule}
                        </p>

                         <Button color="danger" data-id={voiture.id} onClick={this.onSubmit}>changer</Button>
                         </div>         
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

and finally my agent.js file in which I set up the url for each request type:

```
import superagentPromise from 'superagent-promise';
import _superagent from 'superagent';

const superagent = superagentPromise(_superagent,global.Promise);
const API_ROOT='http://localhost:8000/api';
const responseBody = response => response.body;

let token =window.localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');



const tokenPlugin = secured => {
    return (request) => {
        if (token && secured){
            request.set('Authorization',`Bearer ${token}`);
        }
};
};
export const requests={
    get: (url, secured = true)=>{
        return superagent.get(`${API_ROOT}${url}`).use(tokenPlugin(secured)).then(responseBody);
    },
    post: (url, body = null, secured = true) => {
        return superagent.post(`${API_ROOT}${url}`, body).use(tokenPlugin(secured)).then(responseBody);
    },
    put: (url, body = null, secured = true) => {
        return superagent.put(`${API_ROOT}${url}`, body).use(tokenPlugin(secured)).then(responseBody);
    },
    setToken: (newJwtToken) => token = newJwtToken
    };
```

**Edit**

```
import React from 'react';
import {notParked,notParkedAction } from "../actions/actions";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        notParked: (id) => dispatch(notParkedAction(id)),
    }
}
export class VoitureList extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
    }
    onSubmit = event => {

        const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');
        const {notParked}= this.props.notParked(id);
        return notParked(id);

     }

    render() {
        const {voitureList}=this.props;

        return (

            <div className="card mb-3 mt-3 shadow-sm">
                { voitureList.map(voiture => {
                    return (

                            <div className="card-body border-bottom" key={voiture.id}>
                                <p className="card-text mb-0">
                                    {voiture.matricule}
                                </p>

                                <Button color="danger" data-id={voiture.id} onClick={this.onSubmit}>changer</Button>
                            </div>         
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(VoitureList);
```

My Store

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import parkinglist from "./reducers/parkinglist";
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';
import auth from "./reducers/auth";
import {routerReducer} from "react-router-redux";
import parking from "./reducers/parking";
import voitureList from "./reducers/voitureList";
import nameOfYourReducer from "./reducers/voiture";

export default combineReducers({
    parkinglist,
    parking,
    auth,
    router: routerReducer,
    form: formReducer,
    voitureList,
    nameOfYourReducer
});
```

Comment: I think you forgot the `dispatch` parameter in your `mapDispatchToProps` function

Comment: 1. `notParked` ne devrait pas être importé depuis les actions car il n'existe normalement pas dedans
2. Tu devrais aussi utiliser la destructuration dans le onSubmit : `const {notParked} = this.props; return notParked(id);`

Comment: Bon j'ai supprimé notParked de import et j'ai corrigé onSubmit :   ```onSubmit = event => {
        const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');

        const {notParked}= this.prop;
        return notParked(id);
     }```   et ça retourne une erreur ```Cannot read property 'notParked' of undefined```

Comment: Tu as oublié le 's' à `this.props`

Comment: Bon dieu, j'ai remis le 's' et ça retourne ```Uncaught TypeError: notParked is not a function```

Comment: Montre ton store

Comment: Mon store est un peut different du votre mais je pense qu'il à le meme principe. j'ai modifié ma question pour l'inclure

Comment: Tu utilises la méthode createStore ?

Comment: Non, j'utilise deja ce fichier pour gerer l'authentification et d'autres fonctionnalités et je suis pense que ça peut causer des souçis si je change quelque chose. mais j'ai essayé de tester et ça a retourné une erreur ```Expected the reducer to be a function.```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the syntax you use in `notParked` but I would do something like this :

```js
import { notParkedAction } from 'actions.js';

// ...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        notParked: (id) => dispatch(notParkedAction(id)),
    }
}

// mapStateToProps = null is you do not use it

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent)
```

`notParked` will be accessible throug props and `notParkedAction` is your reducer action.

Also it seems you want to use asynchronous function with Redux, you should use redux-thunk.

Remember that the actions should only mutate the state of your store, not doing other stuff

```js
// actions.js

export function notParkedAction(id) {
    return {
        type: 'NOT_PARKED', payload: { id: id }
    }
}
```

```js
// reducer.js

function nameOfYourReducer(state, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'NOT_PARKED':
            return {
                ...sate,
                id: action.payload.id,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }

}

export default nameOfYourReducer;
```

```js
// store.js

import nameOfYourReducer from 'reducer.js';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    nameOfYourReducer,
    // your other reducers...
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

Comment: i'm already using redux-thunk,I modified my mapDispatchToProps and it gives me an error ```notParkedAction' is not defined  no-undef``` how do I add the reducer action ?

Comment: After the edit I keep getting this ```Error: Reducer "nameOfYourReducer" returned undefined during initialization.```

Comment: I modified my reducer function to ```function nameOfYourReducer(state= initialState, action)``` and the error disappeared, instead I'm getting ```Uncaught TypeError: notParked is not a function``` again

Comment: You have to use `this.props.notParked(id)`. Remember that mapDispatchToProps just allowed you to map the dispatch from your action to the props of your component

Comment: Sorry but I edited my question to include the modified list.js, can you tell me what I did wrong in it ?